# Several similar panels GUI Java

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel

I'm creating GUI and I don't know how to resolve my problem. What I'd like to do is to create several panels from PanelClass like i did in Main.

I don't know how:

1. Name buttons in my Panels and gave them some functionality (Like i was trying with button b1)
2. Add to panel3 additional labels, and buttons.

My main class

```
public class Main {

    JFrame f;
    PanelClass panel1, panel2, panel3;
    JButton b1, b2;

    public Main() {

        b1 = new JButton("asasa");

        f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel1 = new PanelClass(b1, b2, panel1);
        panel2 = new PanelClass(b1, b2, panel2);
        panel3 = new PanelClass(b1, b2, panel3);

        f.add(panel1);
        f.add(panel2);
        f.add(panel3);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Main m = new Main();    
    }    
}
```

My Panel class

```
public class PanelClass extends JPanel {

    public PanelClass(JButton btn, JButton btn1, JPanel p) {

        super();
        p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        btn = new JButton();
        btn1 = new JButton();

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        p.add(btn, c);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        p.add(btn1, c);
        add(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want each PanelClass to have it's own Buttons or do you want to be able to rename/access the Main's buttons from the PanelClasses?

Comment: And also passing the reference to the PanelClass to it's own constructor doesn't make much sense to me. What do wish to accomplish with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. A component can only exist in one visible container at a time (unless it is being used as a flyweight renderer).  So putting the same buttons into 3 panels will not work.
2. The code passes a button(s) in the constructor of `PanelClass` which is(are) ignored.  Instead 2 new button instances are created.  Just assign the passed buttons to the ..I was going to say 'class level attributes' when I noted they were not.  Entirely remove 
   `btn = new JButton();` and the text passed in the button constructor will appear.
3. For events, see [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html).

Comment: Thank you! :) My problem was that i didn't remove 'btn = new JButton();', now i can pass my buttons :) And to add additional components to my panels I can create new class which extends PanelClass. Thanks again Andrew :) Btw i know how to write action listeners.

Comment: Cool.  Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the [official Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html). It explains how to add panels, labels, etc.

To edit label names you could use `setText(String name)` method. To add functionalities to buttons you must implement a listener in each one. Add labels like you do in other panels, I don't see the problem.

Comment: Try to run my program and tell me how to name button or edit label in Main class.. and I'll be very grateful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

To add "events" like click and mouse hovers etc - you must implement the correct "Listener" for the Widget. Go through any good tutorial on Swing and it will tell you everything about it. Widgets on screen are regular objects as well, so they can be added to "Collections", iterated and played around with, like regular objects. Take note of THREAD complexities and warning 'Cross-Thread invocation is Injurious To Your Program'.